# Inject functionality from module into class methods

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

I'm working on a little project in ruby, and I'd like to create a module, let's call it Initializer, that modifies the initialization method of all the classes that mix it in. Is this possible? By default, the classes' own .initialize function override anything from the module, is there a way around this?

Comment: It's probably possible, but "modifies the initialization method" is too ambiguous to say for sure, and without an example of what you've tried or are trying to do, we can only guess at solutions.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to plug your code into the initialization process: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html

my advise is: DONT DO IT!

use meta-programming for fancy stuff.